# python reading certificates from file system

Tags: python

I have certificate and key files stored on the file system.
I want to read them in python.

When I mention the filename on the file system level, I use

```
crt_file= r'certificate.crt'
key_file= r'key1.key'
```

The above works fine when I mention the file names directly after r.
However how can I do this when the certificate.crt and key1.key are stored in variables?
example if the following variables hold the filenames:

```
crt_variable='./certificate.crt'
key_variable='./key1.key'
```

In such case using

```
crt_file= r crt_variable
```

leads to an error.
Thanks!

Comment: `r'name'` is not reading a file, it is creating a raw string...

Comment: How are you populating the contents of `crt_variable`? Are you hard coding it in or is it creating them in a loop or something?

Comment: I am creating the entries dynamically. So its not predetermined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these lines are the same

```
crt_file= r'certificate.crt'
crt_file= 'certificate.crt'
```

If you want to open a file, you can use one of these

```
f = open('certificate.crt')  # directly

crt_file= 'certificate.crt'
f = open(crt_file)  # using variable
```